# Get a table rows information based on a unique identifier in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> ID1 </td>
    <td> mr Dawson </td>
    <td> 37 </td>
    <td> New York </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> ID2 </td>
    <td> mr Turner </td>
    <td> 47 </td>
    <td> Washington </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> ID3 </td>
    <td> mr Craig </td>
    <td> 26 </td>
    <td> California </td>
  </tr>
</table
```

**My question is how can i get a rows information i.e. each columns text via unique ID using JQuery?**

I have tried the following:

```
var $Row = $("table").closest('tr').children('td');
var ID = $Row.eq(0).text();
```

But i need to know how to target a specific row instead of returning all rows.

To try to explain better if i was doing it in SQL i might use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID = "VariableName"
```

Output should look like this:

```
ID - mr Dawson - 37 - New York
```

**But i would like to store each columns values as a variable for use elsewhere in the script**

Thanks

Comment: What result do you want to get? What output should be produced?

Comment: @DavidThomas Im not sure if you have used SQL before but i placed a code snippet there which should hopefully help you understand. I can update the question if you like?

Comment: Yes. I want to know if you want a string of HTML, an array of the information, a csv or a JavaScript object.

Comment: @DavidThomas Please see the revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` method to find a row by cell content. For example:

```
var id = 'ID2';

var row = $('table tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text() === id;
});
```

Then you can use this approach to get an array of table cells:

```
var data = $('table tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text() === id;
})
.find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(data);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UXEFZ/3/

Comment: Hi this is a great working example, but how could i return this as an array instead of having to split the string?

Comment: Nevermind i was just being silly it is returning it as an array so i can simply reference each columns value by like this var age = data[2]

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can i get a rows information i.e. each columns text
>   via unique ID using JQuery?

You can use `contains` to get the element by its contents.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcXdx/)**

```
var toSearch = 'ID2';
$("table td:contains('"+toSearch+"')")
```

You probably need [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `closest()` to get the descendants. The closest will get you the ancestor instead of descendants.

```
var $Row = $("table").find('tr:eq(0)'); //here parameter passed to eq in index
var $cell = $Row.find('td:eq(0)');  //here parameter passed to eq in index
```

You can use variable for index

```
row = 1
col = 1
var $Row = $("table").find('tr:eq('+row+')'); //here parameter passed to eq in index
var $cell = $Row.find('td:eq('+col+'0)');  //here parameter passed to eq in index
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the posted desired output, and the lack of any user input/action leading to that output, I'd suggest (albeit untested):

```
var row1 = $('table tr').eq(0).find('td').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(' - ');
```

To get all rows, in a JavaScript object:

```
var allRows = {};
$('table tr').each(function(index){
    allRows['row' + (index + 1)] = $(this).find('td').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(' - ');
});
```

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).